# how to read a value from a xml document based on the user input

Tags: c#

how to read a value from a xml document based on the user input ( for example if user enter id value then all the related values display from xml document)

Comment: You will have to tell us more, in order for us to be able to help. What does your XML structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat vague, but the same things that apply to handling user input in general apply here too. You'd probably proceed something like this:

- Read user input
- Read XML file
- Parse XML into an XML Document object
- Decide, based on user input, which part of the document to display
- Extract the desired part from the document (either by manually walking the document tree, or using XPath)
- Display the extracted part